# Save XML Response into Session in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, xslt

I need to save the xml response into sesssion. but I have tried this But It didn't . but I Have save xml request as session It worked. I Have attached working and non working code. can any one please help me on this. I don't want save the xml response as file.

### Working Code

```
 String xmltest = Session["xmlreq"].ToString();

            SoapClient soap = new SoapClient();
            string prueba = soap.RequestResponseMethod("getHotelValuedAvail", xmltest);
            string tham = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(prueba);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(tham);
            doc.Save(Server.MapPath("hotelrs.xml"));

            XslTransform myXslTransform;
            myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
            myXslTransform.Load(Server.MapPath("hotel.xsl"));
            myXslTransform.Transform(Server.MapPath("hotelrs.xml"), Server.MapPath("transformhotels.xml"));
```

**Non working Code**

```
String xmltest = Session["xmlreq"].ToString();

            SoapClient soap = new SoapClient();
            string prueba = soap.RequestResponseMethod("getHotelValuedAvail", xmltest);
            string tham = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(prueba);
            Session.Add("xmlrs", tham);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(Session["xmlrs"].ToString());
            //doc.Save(Server.MapPath("hotelrs.xml"));

            XmlDocument trdoc = new XmlDocument();
            XslTransform myXslTransform;
            myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
            myXslTransform.Load(Server.MapPath("hotel.xsl"));
            myXslTransform.Transform(doc.InnerXml, trdoc.InnerXml);
            Session.Add("xmltrs", trdoc.InnerXml);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? More importantly, what doesn't the "working code" do that it needs to?

Comment: Is Session["xmlrs"].ToString() has a valid Xml string when you debug it?

Comment: yeah, I got valid xml String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.Declare a variable.
2.store ur xml request data in that variable.
3.Declare another variable say (String Result).
4.Now Result="Call ur method here which will give u a xml response".
5.Session["Outcome"]=Result;
6.No need to use any XMLDocument here.
```

If u want to format ur XML response, use XSLT template.

**In aspx page**

```
 <div id="DivLoad">
     <asp:Xml ID="xmlDaynamic" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Xml>
 </div>
```

**In cs**

```
xmlDaynamic.DocumentContent = session["outcome"];
xmlDaynamic.TransformSource = "yourxslttemplate.xslt";
```

Hope this will help you.